# Creating a dependency for windows service if one stops another needs to start

Tags: windows-service

i created a windows service using C#.

but i want to create a dependency between two services.

if one windows service stops another needs to starts.

can anyone help me on this how to resolve this issue?.

firstly is it possible or not?.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the question not being asked very well (what have you tried? Which Windows version are you using), have a look at [sc config](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc990290%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), that's all you need.